# react-hook-form v7 `watch` type in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I am confused about how to declare a type for `watch` as a prop. Here is an example:

```
// pages/FormContainer.tsx

import { useForm, useWatch } from "react-hook-form";
import FormView from "./FormView";

interface FormInputs {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  age: number;
}

const FormContainer = () => {
  const { control, register } = useForm<FormInputs>({
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: "Jon",
      lastName: "Doe",
      age: 24
    }
  });
  const formData = useWatch({ control });

  return <FormView register={register} formData={formData} />;
};

export default FormContainer;
```

```
// pages/FormView.tsx

import { UseFormReturn } from "react-hook-form";

interface Props {
  register: UseFormReturn["register"];
  formData: UseFormReturn["watch"];
}

const FormView = ({ formData }: Props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        My Name: {formData.firstName} {formData.lastName}
      </h1>
      <h2>I am {formData.age} years old</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FormView;
```

The thing is typescript shows me an error on this `formData={formData}` prop

Here I provided a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-snowflake-3yk8z?file=/src/App.tsx) to be clear on what I mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UseFormReturn["watch"]` will give you back the type of the `watch` function itself - that is, the type of this function:

```
  // `watch` here is of type `UseFormReturn["watch"]
  const { control, register, watch } = useForm<FormInputs>({
    // ...
  });
```

For reference, the return type of this `watch` function is  [`UnpackNestedValues<TFormValues>`](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/892aa0d716aa656a49d588c811efedd6b05dd8c9/src/types/form.ts#L185) .

But - you're not using that function, you're using `useWatch` which returns a subtly different [`UnpackNestedValue<DeepPartialSkipArrayKey<TFieldValues>>`](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/892aa0d716aa656a49d588c811efedd6b05dd8c9/src/useWatch.ts#L22). So, you could change your form type to that:

```
import { UnpackNestedValue, UseFormReturn, DeepPartialSkipArrayKey } from "react-hook-form";
import { FormInputs } from "./FormContainer";

interface Props {
  register: UseFormReturn["register"];
  formData: UnpackNestedValue<DeepPartialSkipArrayKey<FormInputs>>
}
```

Alternatively, since your form object (at least in this example) is very "simple" (it's just key/value pairs effectively), you could use the simpler type declaration of `Partial<FormInputs>` which is functionally equivalent in this case.

[Here's an updated example for you](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-fog-ohy1v).

Answer (score 2):

I found 2 things that will improve and fix your problem.

1. Use the method `watch` returned from `useForm` instead of `useWatch` for getting full form data. You can use `useWatch` for individual form input changes without impacting the root component's render.

```
// Empty watch function will return the full form data.
const formData = watch()
```

2. `watch` returns the full form data, so the prop in the `FormView` component will be `FormInputs`.

```
interface Props {
  register: UseFormReturn["register"];
  formData: FormInputs;
}
```

This should fix your TS errors.